# wigner semi-circle distribution random numbers generation

Tags: density-function, random-generation

I am trying to generate random numbers in Wigner semi-circle distribution. Since this one does not have the analytical solution for the inverse function of the pdf. I wonder if anyone familiar with a standard way to generation random numbers  (RNs) follow this distribution and what are the pros and cons for each method.

My initial guess from what I have researched is, I can use the rejection method or sample method on the uniform distributive random numbers to get the Wigner semi-circle one.

Previously, I have generated normally distributive RNs from uniformly distributive RNs using the Box-Muller transformation. Even I am not a statistics major, it was pretty straight forward process. However, I am having hard time grasp my head around other distributions, specifically this Wigner semi-circle.

Any instructions or source recommendations will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is a shifted, scaled Beta$(3/2,3/2)$ distribution.  Its CDF does have an explicit analytic inverse called the [inverse regularized incomplete beta function](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseBetaRegularized/), but you scarcely need that to generate random values: just look at the graph of the PDF--what kind of geometric figure is it?  Hint: the answer lies in the name of the distribution.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your answer. The graph of the Wigner semi circle pdf is a semicircle or semi ellipse. Are you saying that I just need to use this pdf and sample the uniform random variables to get this Wigner dist?

Comment: Given the shape of the subgraph of the density, there is no need for rejection.

Answer (score 1):

*[Following [whuber's comments:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)]* Since $$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi R^2}\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$$the sub-graph of $f$ $$\mathcal S_R=\{(x,y);0\le y\le f(x)\}$$
is the half-disk of radius $R$. Thus, by the [fundamental lemma of simulation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/292200/7224), 
simulating $X\sim f$ is equivalent to simulating $(X,Y)$ uniformly on $\mathcal S$, which corresponds in spherical coordinates to simulating $$(\rho,\theta)\sim \frac{2}{\pi R}\rho \Bbb I_{(0,R)}(\rho) \Bbb I_{(0,\pi)}(\theta)$$ which is obvious:

1. simulate $U_r,U_a\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$
2. compute $X=R\, \sqrt{U_r} \cos (\pi U_a)$ *[and do not compute $Y=R\, \sqrt{U_r} \sin (\pi U_a)$!]*
3. return $X$

[and shows proximity with the Box-Mueller algorithm, although for the latter $\rho$ is distributed as an Exponential $\mathcal E(1/2)$].

Comment: It may be worth noting that $Y$ need not be calculated at all.  This suggests rejection actually might be more efficient because it requires generating only $4/\pi$ URNs per realization rather than $2$ per realization.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I repeatedly make this mistake...!